# How to set up wifi with ubuntu 18.04.2?

Tags: pi-3b+, ubuntu

I'm trying to use ubuntu OS on my raspberry pi 3 B+.

I have formatted my microSD card to FAT32 and copied the ubuntu-18.04.2-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.

I am able to have the OS working. With keyboard and monitor connected, I am able to get to the command line. In fact, the command line is the only thing I see when I turn on my RPi.

But there is not much I can do since no wifi has been configured yet.

I tried to do 
`sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` to scan for network, but I got this message:

`sudo: iwlist: command not found`

What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this.
Open or save a file in `/etc/netplan` with filename 50-cloud-init.yaml
Enter the file with `sudo nano` and write these

```
network:
   ethernets:
        eth0:
           dhcp4: true
            optional: true

    version: 2
    wifis:
      wlan0:
          optional: true
          access-points:
                  "SSID":
                       password: "password"
          dhcp4: true
```

Write it carefully. Maybe you have to face some indentation error. Fix them carefully.
Save the file then apply

```
sudo netplan apply
```

You get your wifi..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Ubuntu Server on a Pi, but Ubuntu normally uses `NetworkManager` for networking.

The command line interface for `NetworkManager` is `nmcli`.

You may get more help on https://askubuntu.com/